# Using a slug in an emberjs route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to figure out how to use a slug (attribute of my model) in my ember routes to get cleaner urls.

I'd like that my routes look like this:

```
http://www.server.com/#/newsitems/newsitem-title-in-slug-format/1
```

Instead of:

```
http://www.server.com/#/newsitems/1/1
```

As you can see, I'd like to replace the id of the newsitem with the actual slug attribute. Here's how my `Newsitem` model looks like:

```
App.Newsitem = DS.Model.extend({
    slug: DS.attr('string'),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    summary: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

The slug property receives a clean text attribute in this format: `title-in-slug-format`

This is my router map at the moment:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('newsitems', function(){
    this.resource('newsitem', {path:':newsitem_id'});
  });
});
```

I tried replacing the `newsitem_id` with `newsitem_slug` but this isn't working. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Big thanks to Michael for pointing me in the right direction. But, and I think this is because I'm working in the rc-1 version of ember, I didn't had to override the model hook for this. The only thing I had to do is:

```
App.NewsitemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serialize: function(model, params) {
    return { newsitem_id: model.get('slug') };
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few steps required to get this working. First, you'll need to customize your route to override the model hook:

```
App.NewsitemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    console.log("Searching for newsitem with slug: ", params.newsitem_id);
    var newsitems = App.Newsitem.findQuery({ slug: params.newsitem_id });
    newsitems.one("didLoad", function() {
      newsitems.resolve(newsitems.get("firstObject"));
    });
    return newsitems;
  }
});
```

In the above example we query App.Newsitem for records matching the specified slug. It's more complicated than a simple id-based lookup since we need to translate the array of query results into a single record. For more detail on how this works, see: [how-to-find-a-model-by-any-attribute-in-ember-dot-js](http://darthdeus.github.com/blog/2013/01/31/how-to-find-a-model-by-any-attribute-in-ember-dot-js/)

Also you will need to implement `serialize` so that ember linkTo helper will be able to create links correctly

Comment: For some reason the `model` hook isn't called. I don't see the `console.log` appearing in my console. Any ideas? (debugging shows me that the route's `enter` method is called)

Comment: Strange - can you post an example to jsfiddle?

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/bitshiftcop/MqS4G/1/ the console.log in `NewsitemRoute` is not triggered.

Comment: It turns out that the model hook isn't called when you're changing routes but only when you copy/paste a full route in your browser.

Comment: Attempted, but according to error log, ember appears to have depreciated this.

Comment: Yes @bitshiftcop's answer is the way to go with modern versions of ember

Comment: Better place for this logic would be in store. https://gist.github.com/Keeo/0d8d99a50edfdd120bf0