# Tell ember.js to use different key for its model's "id"

Tags: javascript, ember.js, javascript-framework

I am stuck in a situation where I shouldn't return `id` field in the API endpoint. I need to tell ember to use `slug` field for / instead of `id`.

I tried `DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Post', id: {key: 'slug'})`. While this works perfectly fine for `App.Post.find("a-slug-name")`, It messes up for `App.Post.find()` resulting in adding a new model every time it is called. And also assigning `id` to null.

So how should I do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify the attribute that should be used as the `primaryKey` in your Adapter. If you want the `slug` property to serve as your `Post` model `id`, define the `primaryKey` on your Adapter like this:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Post', {
  primaryKey: 'slug'
});
```

### Update

As of Ember-data version `1.0.0-beta.7 canary`, you need to do this instead of the above snippet:

```
App.PostSerializer = DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'slug'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an ember pro, but I had wanted to use a slug instead of an ID recently and did this, wondering if this what you're after?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14967337/472852