# Using a slug in Ember.js 1.x routes

Tags: ember.js, routes

**I'm desperately trying to get slugs in Ember 1.x working.**

My serialize method seems to work fine. I can navigate to my route with no problem using the link-to helper or transitionToRoute method. 
But when I reload my page i get a bunch of errors because my promise resolves in an array of models instead of a single model.

**How do I reduce the result of findQuery to one model?**

I found a helpful answer for an older Ember.js version here:
[Using a slug in an emberjs route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946645/using-a-slug-in-an-emberjs-route/14947194#14947194)
Unfortunately the solution doesn't work anymore. "one" is not defined, so i tried to adapt my code to the current version. According to the promise documentation, a return value in the then method of the promise object should be passed to the next handler. But I'm still getting an array and my errors afterwards.

My route implementation:

```coffee
App.ManageRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    promise = @get('store').findQuery('company', {slug: params.company_id})
    promise.then (models) ->
      return models.get("firstObject")
    return promise;

  serialize: (model, params) ->
    return {company_id: model.get('slug')}
```

**[Update]**

**The solution is to create and return a new Promise object for the single model.**

[See marvilein's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19539675/1030904)

Comment: Can you show your router mapping plz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is create a new promise which represents exactly one object instead of the whole array:

```
App.ManageRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    promise = @get('store').findQuery('company', {slug: params.company_id})
    newPromise = Ember.Deferred.create()
    promise.then (models) ->
      newPromise.resolve(models.get("firstObject"))
    return newPromise;
```

PS: I don't know coffeescript so there may be minor syntactic errors. And i don't know if Ember Data offers something more convenient to achieve this behaviour :-)

Comment: Good example of promise management, you have a typo in the response `newPromise.resolve(model.get("firstObject"))` should be `newPromise.resolve(models.get("firstObject"))`