# ember-data miserable bug duplicate record

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember-data#canary and it has a serious bug when finding record from the store.

`File: router.js`

```
this.resource('games', function() {
    this.route('game', { path: '/:game' });
});
```

`File: games_route.js`

```
App.GamesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {

        // request: GET /api/games
        // response: { games: [
        //               { id: 1, slug: lym, name: lose your marbles }
        // ] }
        return this.store.find('game');
    }
});
```

`File: game_route.js`

```
App.GamesGameRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        // this query causes bogus data to show up.
        // request: GET /api/games/lym
        // response: { game: { id: 1, slug: lym, name: lose your marbles } }
        return this.store.find('game', params.game);

    },

    serialize: function(game) {
        return { game: game.get('slug') };
    }
});
```

`File game_model.js`

```
App.Game = DS.Model.extend({
    slug: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

When I visit `/games` ember-inspector data tab shows 1 game loaded.

```
`id`    `slug`    `name`
 1       lym       lose your marbles
```

When I visit `/games/lym` ember-inspector data tab shows 2 game loaded.

```
`id`    `slug`         `name`
 1       lym            lose your marbles
 lym     undefined      undefined
```

the second data is clearly bogus. I don't know where it comes from and it is causing me trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call `this.store.find('game', params.game)` ember data thinks that `lym` is an id and creates empty record with this `id`. Then it receives payload with actual record and stores with id=1.

Basically, in `store.find` you should use actual id, not a slug, even if your API supports slugs.

Comment: Thank you so much, now i understand the problem, for the solution, can i make use of  `serialize`, `deserialize` hooks on the route, I think they might solve the issue.

Comment: This solved the problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946645/using-a-slug-in-an-emberjs-route.

Comment: Now i need to use slug in the url, in the `model` hook `params` is the slug, I can't use actual id in `store.find` because i have the slug not the id. How do i overcome this? Is there a method like `store.findBySlug`?

Comment: `this.store.find('game', { slug : params.game })`

Comment: aha, i've tried that, it request with query params `/games?slug='bla'` but i need `/games/bla`

Comment: try customising adapter (`findQuery` method)

Comment: I've tried [this](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1326#issuecomment-24710393) but it made no difference, how do you suggest to customize?